# Write a Round Down Function instead of Using math.floor

Tags: python

Instead of using math.floor, the task for me is to write a round down function. My thought is to:
test whether it is a number → whether the number is positive → whether the decimal part >= 0.5 → if yes, print [ round(number) - 1], otherwise print [round(number)]

I basically have two problem. 
The first is how to test whether an input is positive or negative? 
The second is how to write multiple statements with if/elif/else. Because I have two layers of conditions, I don't know what to use.

```py
def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        pass

#2 is input positive? 

#3 s > 0+ decimal >= 0.5;
if s > 0:
    if s - round(s) < 0:
    print (round(s) - 1)
    else: 
    print(round(s)) #decimal < 0.5

else: # s < 0 + decimal >= 0.5
    if s - round (s) > 0: 
    print (round(s) + 1)
    else: # decimal < 0.5
    print (round(s))
```

I expect to round down input.

Comment: You could use `s // 1` to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The `int` function truncates a decimal number allowing you to round down to the next integer.

```
def round_down(x):
    return int(x)-1 if x < 0 else int(x)

round_down(3.5)   # 3
round_down(-4.6)  # -5
```

Comment: No, `int` *truncates* the decimal portion of a non-integer value; that's why you need to handle negative and positive numbers differently.